# PayPal API integration card errors

Tags: php, paypal

I'm trying to integrate the PayPal API for the first time and I'm getting close, but am receiving an error for some reason. I'm using the code from here: [PayPal Integration Wizard](https://devtools-paypal.com/integrationwizard/ecpaypal/billing.php)

I replaced all of the info with static data so I don't have to fill out a form every time. The card info is as follows:

```
    $creditCardType   = "Visa";
    $creditCardNumber = "4111111111111111";
    $expDate          = "012019";
    $cvv2             = "111";
```

It processes it very slowly and I'm getting a 10544 error (The transaction was declined by PayPal. Contact PayPal for more information.) And this is the full error on the page after it attempts to process it:

```
Direct credit card payment API call failed.
Detailed Error Message: Please use a different payment card.
Short Error Message: Transaction cannot be processed.
Error Code: 10544
Error Severity Code: Error
```

I got the card number from here: [Test Cards](https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/vhelp/paypalmanager_help/credit_card_numbers.htm)

I'm not able to find anything in regards to value formatting or standard test data to use and the error is kind of vague, so I'm not sure how to debug this. Has anyone had a similar issue, or have verified working test data?

Answer (score 0):

VISA test cards don't allow you to use CVV, or the expiration date.

Comment: I tried with both blank, and got the following error: `Detailed Error Message: This transaction cannot be processed. Please enter a valid credit card expiration month.` So I tried adding it back in, in `mmyy` format, but it still gave me the same error.